# Wordpress - (theme=Unsigned) disable responsive?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, navigation, themes

Trying to figure out disabling the responsive-ness of my wordpress site - i'm using Unsigned theme and not crazy about the built-in responsive aspect, pretty jarring and creates problems with content.  For the moment i'd like to just edit the code so that the site stays in its normal state and doesn't change when the window is scaled.  Any ideas??
My temp url:

```
http://69.195.124.106/~tipsyoxc/
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to trick your users browser by setting a screen size, but I couldn't find anything with a quick search. Here's a few thoughts off the top of my head:

1.) You could try commenting out the relevant css. Any of the @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) stuff... Easier done if it has all been grouped together in a single section or has its own file.

2.) You could create a 'child theme'(if you haven't already done so), enabling you to override just the css attributes you are unhappy with... will require you to do some hunting with firebug of the specific markup you'd like changed.

3.) Change to a different theme. Wordpress makes it pretty easy to migrate themes. If you don't like the one you're on, or you're not satisfied that you'll be able to sort out the responsive problems with it any time soon, you might choose to make this change sooner that later.